# Unable to write text inside a file using with open r+ PYTHON

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7.

I want to create a script to scan the text file for specific keywords like `want to test` and write or replace string (`b3`). My script:

```
#! usr/bin/python
import re
from os.path import abspath,exists

open_file = abspath("zzwrite.txt")

if exists(open_file):
 with open(open_file,"r+") as write1:
  for line in write1:
   matching = re.match(r'.* want to test (..)',line,re.I)
   if matching:
    print ("Done matching")                                                                                                                       
    write1.write("Success")
    print >> write1,"HALELUJAH"
```

My input text file:

```
I just want to read   432                                                                                                                            
I just want to write 213
I just want to test b3 experiment
I just want to sleep for 4 hours
```

I managed to complete matching as there is a print "done matching" to indicates the codes are able to execute the last 'if' condition but no single string is written or replaced inside the text file. The string `"b3"` is different in every input text file so I do not prefer using `str.replace("b3", "xx")` method. Is there anything I missing in the script?

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: What is `print >> write1, "HALLELUJAH"` supposed to do? That looks like Perl, not Python.

Comment: If `str.replace()` doesn't do what you want, maybe `re.sub()` is what you're looking for?

Comment: I apologized, I am new to Stack Overflow and Python. The vi editor i used can support both perl  and python, I used it to try to see the results

Comment: I have updated my post